# Which layer creation option (lco) to pick in v.in.dxf?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm trying to properly upload a DXF via the GRASS option into QGIS. It is a building structure of LoD2 quality. Unfortunatelly, while the importer runs I always get the error:

> WARNING: Vector map  is 3D.
> Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export
> <in 3D rather than 2D (default).

I couldn't really find a specification what lco one has to pick to properly display 3D structures. From the documentation I tried

- lco="SHPT=POLYGONZ"
- lco="SHPT=POINTZ"
- lco="SHPT=ARCZ"

I'm using QGIS 3.16 on a MAC OS X.

Comment: It seems to me that GDAL DXF driver does not really support 3D objects https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html. I suggest to write a mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask.

Comment: GRASS GIS comes with its own importer: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.in.dxf.html. However, probably QGIS get's stuck in the subsequent internal `v.in.ogr` call in the Processing engine?